# Regex for ESI Number

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a **regex** in C# for below mentioned number

```
31–00–123456–000–0001
```

I am having a problem putting the **dash** in the regex. The number validation is pretty fine.

Comment: Please provide more information. Are there any other limitations to the string? Will each of those sets of digits always be their respective lengths? Are any of the values static? Do you have an example from which you've started?

Comment: `@"^[0-9]{2}–[0-9]{2}–[0-9]{6}–[0-9]{3}–[0-9]{4}$"`?

Comment: That dash character is `U+02013`. Is that the only dash you expect, or is `U+0002D` also acceptable? Be very clear about what you want. And show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
(\d{2})[\–\-](\d{2})[\–\-](\d{6})[\–\-](\d{3})[\–\-](\d{4})
```

So, if you already have code extracted to string variable code and want to check that it  matches then use ^ and $ like here:

```
^(\d{2})[\–\-](\d{2})[\–\-](\d{6})[\–\-](\d{3})[\–\-](\d{4})$
```

According to comments, its better to use [0-9] to reduce other types of degets.

```
^([0-9]{2})[\–\-]([0-9]{2})[\–\-]([0-9]{6})[\–\-]([0-9]{3})[\–\-]([0-9]{4})$
```

Comment: I suggest adding anchors: `^...$` or `bla-bla-bla_valid_ESI_number_bla-bla-bla` will match. Be carefult with `\d`: in .net it means *any unicode digit*, so `۱۳–۱۳–۱۳۱۳۱۳–۱۳۱–۱۳۱۳` (*persian digits*) would match - either switch to `[0-9]` or add `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`

Comment: Thanks for comment. I change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If any kind of [dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm) (e.g. `U+02013`) are acceptable, I suggest using `\p{Pd}` which means any *unicode dash* (**P**unctuation **d**ash). In case the digits should be separated by any *dash*, which, however, must be the *same* within the entire string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]{2}(\p{Pd})[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{6}\1[0-9]{3}\1[0-9]{4}$");
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "31–00–123456–000–0001", // All Dashes
    "31-00-123456-000-0001", // All minuses
    "31–00-123456-000-0001", // Dash then minues
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,25} :: {(regex.IsMatch(test) ? "Matched" : "Failed")}"));

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
31–00–123456–000–0001 :: Matched
31-00-123456-000-0001 :: Matched
31–00-123456-000-0001 :: Failed
```

If you want to tolerate *diffrent dashes* within the same string:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
  @"^[0-9]{2}\p{Pd}[0-9]{2}\p{Pd}[0-9]{6}\p{Pd}[0-9]{3}\p{Pd}[0-9]{4}$");
```